# Coding Type constraints in Java with Generics

Tags: java, generics, types, casting

I'm making a system wherein producer-modules produce events, and consumer-modules consume these events.  A router-class sends events generated by each producer to its list of consumers.  There are different types of events, so both Producer and Consumer classes are parameterized by a generic "EventType".

In my Router code I have a HashMap linking Producers to Consumers.  I want to express the constraint that each consumer for a given Producer must consume the same EventType that that Producer produces (but EventType may be different for different Producers in the table).

Currently, in my Router class, I declare my HashMap as:

```
Map<Producer, List<Consumer>> src_to_consumers;
```

I'd like to do something like

```
Map<Producer<EventType>, List<Consumer<EventType>>> src_to_consumers;
```

Except without the constraint that all producers/consumer-collection pairs must have the same EventType.

Is there a way to do this without casting?

Comment: Do you want to store all your producers and all your consumers in the same map?

Comment: It's not essential, but it seems like a reasonable way to do things.  When producer fires an event, it sends the event and its own ID to the router, which looks it up and sends the event to consumers.  The Map seemed like a logical way to structure this, but I'm open to other options.

Comment: This was just a question to orient my response as your question was rather vague on that. But you gave the info I wanted and I'll post an answer.

Comment: I also should note that I have to be able to switch routing schemes dynamically (it's a machine-learning application and there's one connection scheme for training-mode and one for test), otherwise I would just skip the routers and bind consumers to producers directly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's really a good idea to have everything stored in a single map. I believe you'd be better off with alternatives. Maps are not a one-size-fits-all here. If I were you, I'd totally design an event managing class with as many members as needed. If you can reduce all your needs in a single map, go ahead! Just keep the idea open that you are not restricted to a single object, even if it vaguely looks like you can.

However there are already tools that do the whole management of events for you. They're called event-buses. There are a lot of them around and searching for them will give you many results, just pick the one that suits your needs most.

Comment: Hmmm.. point taken but there is some advantage to being able to handle things with a generic routing class rather than having a class with one member per Producer & Consumer.  In my case I want to separate the routing logic (which may process events in depth-first vs breadth-first order depending on implementation) into a different class from the connection logic (which builds the graph of modules).  But I guess what you're saying is if I want this, I have to cast.

Comment: @Peter Okay, given your answer, I believe I might not have been explicit enough. You can have one map, that's not the issue. Just, put all the constraints on the API you're providing instead of the map.

Answer (score 0):

In the end:

There is no way to add this type of constraint on a data type.  What I did do is make a new object type "ModuleLinks" that (for my case) binds producers and consumers, and make a collection of those.

```
class ModuleLinks<EventType>{
    Producer<EventType> producer;
    List<Consumer<EventType>> consumers;
    ...
    }
```

You can then make your `HashMap<Producer, ModuleLinks<EventType>>`.